# Azure Devops multiple triggers condition in a single file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

Is it possible to have a single file `azure-pipelines.yaml` that can :

- Trigger a `job A` on a push from any branch BUT `main`
- Trigger a `job B` on PR to `main` and all subsequent commit on that PR
- Trigger a `job C` when `main` is merged

I have tried to play arround with `trigger`, `pr` keywords and even with `condition()`, `variables['Build.Reason']`,  or `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` but I didn't manage to reach the expected result.

I start thinking it cannot be done with a single file - am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set conditions on your stages to run depending on a variable but I am not pretty sure this will work with your conditions. Maybe you could also combine some variable values.

For example source branch main and pr is created.

```
and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
```

Azure documentation sample:

```
variables:
  isMain: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')]

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage A!

- stage: B
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMain, 'true'))
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage B!
      - script: echo $(isMain)
```

Keep in mind that triggers are appending resources. This means that if you specify a trigger like the below, it will be triggered whether the branch filter is triggered OR the pr is created.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'  

pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - current
```

As you said this can be accomplished for sure with separate files for the pipelines.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is possible by using trigger with include and exclude branches as below

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - stage
    - releases/*
    exclude:
    - master
```

Refer [CI triggers in Azure Repos Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) documentation to have more understanding.

Comment: My problem is not to run those jobs independently but having them all declared in a single file